# Boost filesystem weakly_canonical does not resolve relative paths without parent folders

Tags: c++, boost-filesystem

I want to obtain an absolute canonical path given a relative path with boost filesystem to be used in both windows and linux. I want it to work also for non-existing paths.

I am using weakly_canonical(path relativePath), available since boost 1.60, in order to do it. But it does not behave as expected (at least in windows).

When passing a relative path without parent folders, i.e. a raw filename or folder name such as "foo", weakly_canonical returns the same untouched path ("foo" in this case), whereas absolute(path relativePath) prepends the current path to it (as I expected) ("current_dir/foo").

So finally, I am forced to call first absolute and then weakly_canonical to make it work.

See a snippet with the two cases.

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

using boost::filesystem;
path relativePath("foo");
path canonical_path = weakly_canonical(relativePath);
path abs_canonical_path = weakly_canonical(absolute(relativePath));
std::cout << "Using weakly_canonical: "
          << canonical_path.string()
          << std::endl;
std::cout << "Using weakly_canonical and absolute: " 
          << abs_canonical_path.string()
          << std::endl;
```

For example if current_path is "C:\path\to\some\folder", I am obtaining:

1. relativePath = "./foo"

```
Using weakly_canonical: C:\path\to\some\folder\foo
Using weakly_canonical and absolute: C:\path\to\some\folder\foo
```

2. relativePath = "../foo"

```
Using weakly_canonical: C:\path\to\some\foo
Using weakly_canonical and absolute: C:\path\to\some\foo
```

3. relativePath = "foo"

```
Using weakly_canonical: foo
Using weakly_canonical and absolute: C:\path\to\some\folder\foo
```

This last case is what puzzles me because I would expect weakly_canonical to also prepend the current working dir.

Is it correct to use absolute and weakly_canonical together? Or am I misusing weakly_canonical?

Answer (score 2):

[Documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#weakly_canonical) says: "*Returns: A path composed of the result of calling the `canonical` function on a path composed of the leading elements of `p` that exist, if any, followed by the elements of `p` that do not exist, if any.*"

The important bits are that `canonical` (which indeed constructs an absolute path) is only called if there are leading elements of `p` that actually exist.

If you call `weakly_canonical` on a relative path where the first element does not exist, `canonical` is simply not called and the following part is just normalized if dots are used.
So `weakly_canonical("foo")` could either return `foo` if this path does not
exist or an absolute path if it does exist.

This behavior is the same for the different implementations of `std::filesystem::weakly_canonical` I could test.

If you want to be sure to have an absolute form of the canonical path, you can call `absolute` just after `weakly_canonical`:

```
boost::filesystem::absolute(boost::filesystem::weakly_canonical("foo"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#weakly_canonical) says "*Returns p with symlinks resolved and the result normalized*" It does not say that it would make the full path. Your "foo" has no symlinks and no dots in the path.

Comment: The documentation says more specifically that: "Returns: A path composed of the result of calling the canonical function on a path composed of the leading elements of p that exist, if any, followed by the elements of p that do not exist, if any", and the canonical function says: "Converts p, which must exist, to an absolute path that has no symbolic link, dot, or dot-dot elements". So I understand that weakly_canonical should make the full path. Am I wrong?